# When should I use VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED when creating subpasses?

Tags: specifications, vulkan

If I don't need attachments in a subpass, I would *not* include the attachment and update the attachment count accordingly in `VkSubpassDescription`.

I see that `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED` is a possible value for `VkAttachmentReference.attachment`. What features does it provide over the original route?

(Originally, I thought it might be a way to preserve the values of attachments between subpasses, but `pPreserveAttachments` already does that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragment shader outputs are bound to a `Location` index. This is an index into the subpass's `pColorAttachments` array.

If you have a shader that, for whatever reason, writes to locations 0 and 2, then that means `pColorAttachments` has to have 3 entries. Entry index 1 is `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`.

Now, why would your shader do that? Well, it is possible to use the same shader module in different pipelines intended for different subpasses. In one subpass, maybe there are 3 attachments, and this shader simply doesn't write to location 1 (it turns off writes to that attachment as part of the pipeline setup). In another subpass, there are only 2 attachments, but you want to use the same shader.

Yeah, you could theoretically use specialization constants to change the `Location` index. I wouldn't say this is a widely used or highly useful feature. But there's not reason to not support it.

Comment: Can I write to attachment 3 in the shader yet in the render pass and framebuffer only have one attachment, and set the other all the rest to unused? I'm thinking this will come in handy by writing to the picking buffer at 3, and/or writing normals/reflection at 2, then I can use different render passes depending on if I'm picking or need lighting. Or I suppose a simpler example, my shader writes to colour at location 0, and I want to do a depth-only pass, then I give a VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED to the pColourAttachments.